# Is it possible to change the position of the Remote Desktop Connection client bar?

Tags: remote-desktop

Is it possible to change the position of the Remote Desktop Connection client bar? It's really annoying that I can only seem to drag it in the top area of the window.

Can I move the bar so it appears on the right-hand side of the window?

Answer (score 16):

It is now possible to remove it all together.  In the Remote Desktop Connection windows, under the Display tab, uncheck the "Display the connection bar when I use the full screen."

Comment: With the above option... Is the best way to temporary 'bring it back' with Ctrl + Alt + Break like mentioned below (but that minimizes the window at same time and have to maximize it again)?

Comment: where is this? how do I navigate to it?

Answer (score 10):

If you can't see the bar - You can get out of Remote desktop ..and go back to local computer using `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Break`

Comment: An alternative is `Ctrl` + `Fn` + `Alt` + `Home` if you don't have a `Break` key.

Answer (score 6):

If you hover to the left of the pin, you will get a cursor which shows you that you can resize the bar.  And if you click on your computer's name, you can drag it left or right.  That allows me to put it just left of the minimize button on full screen windows.

If only Microsoft would give us a way of remembering where we put it and saving that for our next session.

Comment: Whats worse: I work with two screens and the bar (if minimized) appears on the active screen. So if it was on the right and resized/moved and you go to the other screen and then back, the position/size is reset...

Answer (score 2):

### No

But you can have it minimise if you click the pin icon, to see it again bring your mouse up to the top of the screen.

[Here is a list of all the options](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff404238.aspx) you have for a remote desktop connection, they all seem to focus on visual output coming from the remote machine, and security nothing about the client bar.

Comment: It's still annoying minimized, like apps that require me to bring my cursor to the top of the screen a lot.  For example, I dunno, a *web browser*.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not. For info, there is a complete list of the available customisations here:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=139899

As microsoft's links have a habit of going dead, the page title is:

"RDP Settings for Remote Desktop Services in Windows Server 2008 R2"

Answer (score 2):

Extending on [Chris Tindalls answer](https://superuser.com/a/600592), the best way to temporarily bring back the connection bar **without** leaving full screen mode is Ctrl+Alt+Home

Answer (score 1):

As of 2020, it is now possible to move the bar.  On the extreme left there is the "pin" icon.  If you click that, you can drag the bar where you want.

If you just leave it there, it'll vanish after a moment, but reappear if you move your mouse to the top of the screen.

While it's visible, if you click on the "pin" icon again, it'll stay put but in the new place.

Comment: Regarding "As of 2020", the question is not about moving the bar left or right, it's about moving it anywhere. It's still only possible to move it left or right.

Comment: Please read the question: The question already states that they are already able to move the bar since 2011, so what you have said was already possible and doesn't answer the question of moving the bar to the sides of the screen.

Comment: It's not a perfect match for the original question...but this *did* match my issue, which was how to move the bar from one screen to another.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> works fine for when you want to switch to the local machine. However, it will remain there until you do so. After returning to RD it will go away again.

Answer (score 0):

Option "floating_toolbar_placement" is available in the remmina.pref config file. Setting this equal (=) to 1 will position the floating toolbar to the bottom of the screen. Default is 0 for the top of screen.